# When I instantiate a custom List class the internal array doesn't behave as expected

Tags: java, arrays, list, class, instantiation

Here is a link to the List class and the test: [List and Test classes](https://gist.github.com/3886805)

And here are the results when I print out the array:

68
93
80
111
103
100
106
0
78
87
78
141
72
etc...

The array should only have a size of 10 and be filled with zeros. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please don't make us go to your code; bring your code to us.

Comment: Your code seems to print out all `0`s as it should.. (I ran it myself)

Comment: `if(full != true)` very, very ugly. Should be `if (!full)`.

Comment: Another ugly construct `if(items == array.length) full = true;`, should be simply `full = items == array.length`.

Comment: Ran the code. In my case it also prints only zeros.

Comment: My apologies Dave, I thought that would be the easiest way to show it. In the future I'll include it directly in the post. And thank you Jagger for the comments on my coding style, I am always glad to have the chance to improve. It seems the problem is only on my computer then, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: see the comments below.**

When you're copying the arrays, you're copying the value of that array (which is a reference to the original).

You need to perform a deep copy of the array, otherwise this line:

```
int[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length*2)
```

doesn't give you a new array holding the values of the original, it just puts the reference value of the old array to the new one.

Basically, you should iterate through the contents of the original array and create a new array if you need to perform a copy of the contents and leave the original unmodified.

Comment: Not true. Here is an example `int[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; int[] copyArray = Arrays.copyOf(intArray, intArray.length << 1); intArray[0] = 6; System.out.println(intArray.length); System.out.println(copyArray.length); System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray)); System.out.println(Arrays.toString(copyArray));`. And here is what it prints out `5 10 [6, 2, 3, 4, 5] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. So no references are copied and a new array is created, I do not know from where you have taken this.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. I was going off of something I helped someone with last week. I think they might have used clone() instead of copyOf() and I just wasn't paying enough attention to the code here.